# Opening show view using bootstrap3 modal in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

While sending get request to the client its giving 500 internal server error. I'm using bootstrap 3, rails 4 combined with several other gems like devise, mysql database.

Error log:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/admin_panel/hotels/6 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?body=1:9632
send jquery.js?body=1:9632
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:9177
$.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js?body=1:84
$.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js?body=1:164
(anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js?body=1:342
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:4642
elemData.handle
```

Controller:

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_admin_panel!
    def index
        @hotels = Hotel.all
    end
    def show
        @hotels = Hotel.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
           format.html
           format.json { render json: @hotels }
        end
    end
```

show.haml:

```
 :javascript
    $('#myModal').html('#{j render("show")}');
```

_show.haml

```
#myModal
    %table.table.table-hover
        %tr
            %td ID
            %td= @hotels.id
        %tr
            %td Hotel Name
            %td= @hotels.hotel_name
        %tr
            %td Description
            %td= @hotels.description
        %tr
            %td Address
            %td= @hotels.address
        %tr
            %td Postal Code
            %td= @hotels.postal_code
        %tr
            %td City
            %td= @hotels.city
        %tr
            %td State
            %td= @hotels.state
        %tr
            %td Country
            %td= @hotels.country
        %tr
            %td Longitude
            %td= @hotels.longitude
        %tr
            %td Latitude
            %td= @hotels.latitude
        %tr
            %td Rooms
            %td= @hotels.rooms
        %tr
            %td Price
            %td= @hotels.price
    %p= link_to 'Back', hotels_path
```

Application.js:

```
var clickOnPopupLink = function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.static-popup-link', function(){
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
}

clickOnPopupLink();
```

index.haml

```
= link_to 'View', hotel, {:remote => 'true', 'class' => 'static-popup-link'}
  .modal.hide.fade#myModal{:tabindex => '-1', :role => 'dialog', :'data-backdrop' => 'static', :'data-keyboard' => 'false'} Loading...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to dinamically add content in a modal about your hotels every time a user click in your body.
One way is using javascript like response in your action and not html, so change your action show with:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
end
```

rename show.haml to show.js.haml and fill with this code:

```
:plain
$('#myModal').html('#{escape_javascript(render(partial: "show") )}');
```

In your partial view _show.haml for showing information about all your hotels you would use @hotels.each

Comment: Now the error message is gone and the modal is opening however, nothing loads inside modal.

Comment: I edited my message to change the javascript file to erb template

Comment: Can I use combination of haml and erb templates for single controller action, since I have used haml throughout this project.

Comment: You can use both, but i edited my response with haml template

Comment: I'm successfully getting response however, data is still not showing in the front end. 

Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/admin_panel/hotels/6
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Response tab:
<div class='col-md-12 main'>
          
          $('#myModal').html('<div class=\'modal hide fade\' id=\'ajax-modal\' tabindex=\'-1\'>\n  <div class=\'modal-header\'>\n    <button aria-hidden=\'true\' class=\'close\' data-dismiss=\'modal\' type=\'button\'>&times;<\/button>\n    <h3 class=\'modal-title\'>Campustask<\/h3>\n....